# Android had yet not differentiated DC-HSPA networks. is there any way round?

Tags: java, android, cellular-network

Android Still not differentiates DC-HSPA and HSPA+ networks in the as no refrence can be found in [ServiceState class](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/ServiceState.java#L72) if you observe it from line no 72 to 107

is there any other way to differentiate it out?

Comment: TelephonyManager is the more appropriate location to get the network type.  In any case, DC-HSPA is still not included in Android 4.4 ([HERE](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#L583) is a link to the current list).  

A request to add DC-HSPA to the Android framework has been filed on the Android project bug tracker; "star" it [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61697) to help attract Google's attention.

Comment: Is there any way it can be built independent of Google?

Comment: If you can come up with your own method to capture the network type directly from the radio, it could be possible. But it is difficult to learn how to access the radio directly, not to mention the security mechanisms you may encounter. And each device would be different.